# 'Project needs to be deployed before it can be started' after successful deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I'm trying to remote debug a new background IOT app on my Raspberry Pi 3 in VS2015 Update 3. At first I had trouble with 'Command failed: 0x800705b4', which I solved by changing the remote machine name to the IP address and the '8116' port as instructed via the IOT Device Portal, which I launched from the IoT Dashboard. I also changed my authentication to 'None'. Both of these can connect to the raspberry pi without a problem. Once I changed the path to include the port and no authentication, I'm able to deploy successfully from visual studio. The output window literally says 'deployment complete', then the next thing that happens is an error telling me that I have to deploy the project before I can debug it. This makes no sense.

I've tried changing my authentication back to Universal unencrypted, but that causes the other issue again. I've tried just right-clicking and selecting 'deploy', which is successful, and then trying right-click and selecting 'start new instance', but for some reason that tells me it's not deployed yet. Note, I'm on the IOT Device Portal connected to the raspberry pi and I can see the app get loaded in when I deploy, so it seems like an issue with visual studio, not the connection. Help! I've also done a windows update on the raspberry pi but no updates seemed to show up.

-Raspberry Pi 3, OS Version 10.0.14393.187 (Windows IoT, not insider version)
-My computer has developer mode turned on and I'm running Windows 10 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3. (I just ran the latest update 3 patch as well, today).
-Yes, I've got 'ARM' selected.
-Yes, I've tried with 'deploy' on in the configuration manager, although I prefer not to deploy every time, not to mention when I do, I get an error saying it's already installed on the remote machine, so I have to delete it first.
-Yes, I've tried killing the msvmon.exe processes as described in other posts.
-My app has no warnings or errors.

Comment: Check the solution properties to make sure that the project you expect to deploy is marked for deployment.  Also make sure you have told it which project is the one to run.

Comment: Yep, I've got it set as the single startup project. Also, as noted above, I have tried with the 'deploy' checkbox on and off in the build configuration... they both behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it's working now after changing the device name, changing the administrator password (p@ssw0rd) to something new, and setting a remote debugging pin. I used the dns name via the automatic find option and it worked, even though it needed the IP before.

Comment: I've had the exact problem you describe in your question plaguing me for the last 4 hours! I discarded this solution as I thought it couldn't possibly solve anything.. But guess what?! Doing exactly as you describe, my Pi is now working and debugging correctly! Thanks for the solution.